# Can a private school refuse admission despite the student having the requisite cut-off?

Tags: discrimination, india, education, school

My brother is being refused admission to a school that I attended for 9 years. This is because when I was in school, the teachers traumatised me and we complained about it in a feedback form. The principal of the school called me to her office and gave me a earful for "not being grateful" to the school for all the opportunities they gave me.

This year, my brother applied to the school (because they have good facilities and provide the subjects that he wants). But the principal refused to give him a place in the school because of how "disrespectful" I was even though he has the marks to get in. Is this legal and if not what can I do against it?

Comment: Suppose a school has 10 spots open, and 50 applicants with the requisite marks, do you think they are *obligated* to admit all 50??

Answer (score 6):

This sucks.  It is also legal.  It's a private school, they can admit who they like (provided they don't discriminate on the grounds of protected characteristics like "religion" or "caste").

Answer (score 6):

It is entirely legal. The school has no obligation to admit any particular student unless there is an alumnus preference clause in their admission agreements.